# How would you transfer data to the <div> within ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have a button:

```
a href='javascript:void(null)' onclick = "showDialog()" class='btn_history' id='@Model.contractFees.ElementAt(loop).FeeId' title='History'>History
```

That calls this script:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function showDialog() {
    $("#history_dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Okay": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Which uses this div:

```
<div id='history_dialog' title="Contract Fee History" style="display: none">
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" id="row_id" name="row_id" value="" />
<table id='historyOFee' width="100%" class="tan">
    <thead> 
        <tr class="top"> 
            <th>Effective Date</th> 
            <th>End Date</th> 
            <th>Fee %</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        @foreach (ContractFee fee in Model.fullListOfFees.ToList())
        {

            <tr>
            <td>
             <text>@fee.EffectiveDate</text>
            </td>
            <td>
            <text>@fee.EndDate</text>
            </td>
            <td>
            <text>@fee.FeeRate</text>
            </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
 </table>
</fieldset>
```

My question is how to get the button id as a value in the div.

I really need to do this:

```
@foreach(ContractFee fee in Model.fullListOfFees.where(x =>x.ID == buttonId)
```

I have tried passing values into the script, passing values into the model, and ViewBag with no luck.

Comment: Where is the div (in the same file or in another one)?

Comment: If it is in the same file you cannot use server data as you do not do any request to the server. Everything is done inside the browser and you cannot access server data. You should make an AJAX call and retrieve JSON data when the button is pushed. Then populate <div> with the data.

Comment: the dialog your are opening has already been present on the page so you can not do it using jquery.

Comment: "I have tried passing values into the script" how you do that

Answer (score 0):

"My question is how to get the button id as a value in the div."

Using Ajax, make an asynchronous call and return the data you need as a JSON object. In order to "refresh" the div on button click, you should put it in a separate partial view and re-populate it on success, when the AJAX call returns.